# Coroutine bug using LibGDX on Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, libgdx, kotlin-coroutines

I'm developing a game project on Kotlin using LibGDX and everything worked fine until I have created the Game class (before that I was testing on a single class extended by ApplicationAdapter()).
The issue comes with a Coroutine (I know it's weird to work with that with LibGDX) that constainly increases or reduces size of 4 boxes to get a lettency effect while class is running. I don't have experience working with LibGDX and I'm still trying to understand some basics concepts. So it seems like the effect is working but at some point it stops working.Everything is working well (including the touch)

I've tried to make changes on the dispose() method and in the camera.

The game class:

```
class game : Game(){

    public var batch: SpriteBatch? = null
    public var font_generator : FreeTypeFontGenerator? = null
    public var font_parameter = FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter()
    public var font : BitmapFont? = null
    public var touch : Vector3 = Vector3()
    public var isDisplaying : Boolean = true

    override fun create() {
        batch = SpriteBatch()
        setFontConfig()
        font_generator = FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/indie_flower.ttf"))
        font = font_generator?.generateFont(font_parameter)
        setScreen(escollir_color(this))
    }

    override fun render() {
        super.render()

    }

    override fun dispose() {
        batch!!.dispose()
        font!!.dispose()
    }
    private fun setFontConfig(){
        font_parameter.size=60
        font_parameter.shadowOffsetX=2
        font_parameter.shadowOffsetY=2
        font_parameter.shadowColor = Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
        font_parameter.color = Color(255f, 255f, 255f, 1f)

    }

}
```

```
package com.la_rateta.game

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Camera
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.GlyphLayout
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class escollir_color(game: game) :  Screen{

    private lateinit var gameInstance : game
    private var camera : OrthographicCamera = OrthographicCamera()
    private var image: ArrayList<Texture?> = ArrayList()
    private var form : ArrayList<Rectangle> = ArrayList()
    private var enterCoroutine : Boolean = true
    private var enunciats : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    private var random : Int? = null
    private var layout : GlyphLayout? = null

    init {
        gameInstance = game
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800f, 400f)
        layout = GlyphLayout()
        addColors()
        randomText()
    }

    override fun render(delta : Float) {
        camera.update()
        gameInstance.batch!!.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)

        gameInstance.batch!!.begin()
        gameInstance.font!!.draw(gameInstance.batch, enunciats[random!!].toString(), (800-layout!!.width)/2, 370f)
        gameInstance.batch!!.end()
        gameInstance.batch!!.begin()
        for (i in 0 until image.size){
            gameInstance.batch!!.draw(image[i], form[i].x, form[i].y, form[i].width, form[i].height)

        }
        extendSize()
        gameInstance.batch!!.end()

        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            touching()
        }
    }


    private fun addColors(){
        var display : Rectangle = Rectangle()
        image?.add(Texture("yellow_color.jpg"))
        display.x = 100f; display.y = 200f; display.width = 80f; display.height = 80f
        form.add(display)

        display = Rectangle()
        image?.add(Texture("green_color.png"))
        display.x = 210f; display.y = 200f; display.width = 80f; display.height = 80f
        form.add(display)

        display = Rectangle()
        image?.add(Texture("pink_color.jpg"))
        display.x = 100f; display.y = 90f; display.width = 80f; display.height = 80f
        form.add(display)

        display = Rectangle()
        image?.add(Texture("blue_color.jpg"))
        display.x = 210f; display.y = 90f; display.width = 80f; display.height = 80f
        form.add(display)

        display = Rectangle()
        image?.add(Texture("ribbon.png"))
        display.x = 500f; display.y = 90f; display.width = 200f; display.height = 200f
        form.add(display)


    }
    private fun randomText(){
        enunciats.add("El llaç és de color groc")
        enunciats.add("El llaç és de color verd")
        enunciats.add("El llaç és de color rosa")
        enunciats.add("El llaç és de color blau")

        random = (0..3).random()
        layout!!.setText(gameInstance.font, enunciats[random!!].toString())
    }

    private fun extendSize(){
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
                while(gameInstance.isDisplaying){
                    for (i in 0 until form.size-1){
                        form[i].width = 80f; form[i].height = 80f
                    }
                    for (i in 0 until 15){
                        for (i in 0 until form.size-1){
                            form[i].width += 1f; form[i].height += 1f
                            Gdx.app.log("1", "Coroutine 1a part");
                        }
                        delay(100)
                    }
                    for (j in 0 until 15){
                        for (j in 0 until form.size-1){
                            form[j].width -= 1f; form[j].height -= 1f
                            Gdx.app.log("1", "Coroutine 2a part");
                        }
                        delay(100)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    override fun dispose() {
        gameInstance.batch!!.dispose()
        gameInstance.font_generator!!.dispose()
    }

    private fun touching(){
        gameInstance.touch.set(Gdx.input.getX().toFloat(), Gdx.input.getY().toFloat(), 0f)
        camera.unproject(gameInstance.touch)

        for(i in 0 until form.size){
            if (form[i].contains(gameInstance.touch.x, gameInstance.touch.y)){
                when (i){
                    0 -> {
                        image?.removeAt(4)
                        image?.add(4, Texture("yellow_ribbon.png"))

                    }
                    1 -> {
                        image?.removeAt(4)
                        image?.add(4, Texture("green_ribbon.png"))
                    }
                    2 ->{
                        image?.removeAt(4)
                        image?.add(4, Texture("pink_ribbon.png"))
                    }
                    3 -> {
                        image?.removeAt(4)
                        image?.add(4, Texture("blue_ribbon.png"))
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
  


}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Dispatchers.Main` is inappropriate to use for updating your game objects. You’re working with stuff that isn’t thread-safe, and libGDX doesn’t use the Main thread, so you’re mixing threads.

If you want to use coroutines in libGDX, you’ll want to use a dispatcher that is single-threaded and using the OpenGL thread (the game thread). Look up the libKtx library on GitHub. It has a [coroutines module](https://github.com/libktx/ktx/blob/master/async/README.md) that sets up the dispatcher and a game CoroutineScope for you so you can use that to launch your coroutines. Then you would use `KtxAsync.launch` without specifying a dispatcher instead of using `GlobalScope.launch`. Or you can create CoroutineScopes that are scoped to your individual screens. Probably more appropriate for what you’re doing so you won’t have to use hacks like `if (isDisplaying)`.

I’m not positive this is your only issue, as you didn’t describe what “stops working” means exactly.